# Looking at a problem with image overlapping nav bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I got this issue that a portrait is overlapping my nav bar.
And I've been looking around and trying to find a fix, but no luck.
I have tried z-index, but sadly didn't work at all.

My code for the section:

```css
/*Navbar CSS*/

.topNavMain,
.topNavMain ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(227, 232, 237, 0.40);
  color: #5f6f81;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 60px;
  z-index: 999 !important;
}


/*img class CSS*/

.imgPortrait {
  width: 80%;
  z-index: -999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutMe" class="contentS">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col slideIn margin-fix">
        <h2 class="contentT">About me</h2>
        <p class="shortText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce mollis pretium felis id ultricies. Sed libero risus, volutpat vel rhoncus et, auctor non ipsum. <br> Praesent sollicitudin nibh nisl, et sagittis nulla ornare at.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col slideIn2">
        <img src="img/portrait.jpg" alt="" class="imgPortrait img-fluid"></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Screenshot of my issue:
[Click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v8ht.jpg)

Comment: Please give your site url..

Comment: Sorry, website is local, so I can't do much sorry.

Comment: Your HTML and CSS seems different, not relatable, where is HTML for ul nav

Comment: What do you mean? I mean I can post more css, for context?

Comment: I think you need to add your full html and css..

Comment: Yeah please share as much as possible. Ideally if you can recreate the issue in a snippet, you're more likely to get a quick response.

Comment: Yeah sec, I'm gonna get a friend to upload my files. So you can see it in full.

Comment: Give me a shout when you've updated it

Comment: http://thomasmaneschijn.com/lukas/

Comment: Should be uploaded probably.

Comment: @SamJohnson U there?

Comment: Adding an answer now.

Comment: Done - let me know if that works.

Comment: @SamJohnson Thank you, worked smoothly, you can see it work on the website if you feel like it.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a simple fix, you need to apply a z-index to the `div` containing the nav, not just the `ul`.

```
#navDiv {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the arrows of the carousal overlapped with the navbar. As the arrow icons already had z-index as 1 so in my case I had to make the z-index of the navbar div as 2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

z-index does not work for position: static . It only works for position: relative, absolute, fixed or sticky.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).